# Including all @OneToMany Entities in Restful-WebService response?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jpa, bidirectional-relation

First Post here,so please excuse any noobish approaches to best get your attention / help me you find an answer. :)

Without going into too much detail of my actual Program:

I have a **User** who can register many **Devices** which can be associated to many **Remotes** which can have many **Buttons** ( Commands (LIRC Commands to be precise)).

Here is my Code for the 4 Entities' **@ManyToOne** and **@OneToMany** Sections.

USERS

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Devices> devices;
```

DEVICES

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private Users user;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "device")
private List<Remotes> remotes;
```

REMOTES

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "DEVICE_ID")
private Devices device;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "remote")
private List<Commands> commands;
```

COMMANDS

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "REMOTE_ID")
private Remotes remote;
```

They all work fine and the Database entries all have the appropriate foreign keys, and if I've understood correctly this should be bi-directional.

To My Question:

Is there a way my Restful Webservice Request can respond to a findAll() on the User by not only responding with the **User** but also with all the data from **Devices** in turn returning all the **Devices' Remote's** and the **Commands** which belong to the **Remote**.

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/json"})
public List<Users> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

If need be I'll have to go through all the entities and patch together a JSON myself, but before I embark on that journey I was wondering if there's an easier way of going about my problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Fix:

I had to change the Fetch and cascade settings for all of my @OneToMany's and @ManyToOnes' in my Entities.

```
@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private Users user;

@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "device",
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
private List<Remotes> remotes;
```